# Create kibana visualizations using Chart.js or elastic-charts

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, visualization, elk

I want to create the charts/bar graphs/ pie plots similar to one which is created by kibana (in dashboard).

By using chart.js / elastic-charts on frontend and the data present in my elastic search instance.

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the discussion on the similar topic by one of team-members from elastic

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-does-kibana-generates-the-visualizations/298721/4

Comment: yeah but she haven't explained how to generate graph in my custom react / angular app

Comment: you can use custom exporter and generate Iframe for the specific widget